# how to align x,y ticks to frame in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plotly

```
fig = plt.figure() # create figure    

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1) # add subplot 1 (1 row, 2 columns, first plot)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2) # add subplot 2 (1 row, 2 columns, second plot).

df_china_india.plot(kind='box', figsize=(15,6), color='blue', vert=False, ax=ax0)
ax0.set_title('Box Plots of Immigrants from China and India (1980 - 2013)')
ax0.set_xlabel('Number of Immigrants')
ax0.set_ylabel('Countries')

df_china_india.plot(kind='line', figsize=(15,6), ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Box Plots of Immigrants from China and India (1980 - 2013)')
ax1.set_xlabel('Years')
```

in both the plots my x and y axis is moved away from frame.
like in second plot start position of line is not starting from the 0 in frame.
I want 1980 on the line of frame in ax1 and o on frame line in ax0.

how to fix this

[image]

Comment: You can specify the limits to start at 0 using `xlim` as `plt.xlim(0, 44000)` and `plt.xlim(1980, 2013)`

Comment: To fix the lower limit to zero, you can use `ax.set_xlim(0,None)` - this will let the upper limit autoscale.